# Kafka broker thinks there are no brokers (not even itself)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

## Question

I am trying to run a single Kafka instance in docker. I can create topics but cannot consume from or produce to them. When I try my Kafka broker logs an error message.

```
kafka_1      | [2019-03-24 16:45:05,263] ERROR [KafkaApi-5] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

I don't understand the `Number of alive brokers '0'` bit as it is a Kafka broker that is logging this so surely there must be at least one broker (itself)?

I am using the default `server.properties` file with the following changes:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.109:9092
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181
```

where `192.168.0.109` is my host machine IP.

## Files

### docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  zookeeper:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: zookeeper.dockerfile
      network: host
    image: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: kafka.dockerfile
      network: host
    image: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
```

### kafka.dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.7

# Set the name for a non-priliaged user
ENV APPUSER=appuser

# Install dependnacies
RUN apk add bash
RUN apk add openjdk8-jre

# Add a non-privilaged user and change into it's home directory
RUN adduser -D $APPUSER
WORKDIR /home/$APPUSER

# Download kafka and set its owner to $APPUSER
RUN wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz
RUN chown $APPUSER kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz

# Change to the non-privilaged user
USER $APPUSER

# Extract kafka
RUN tar -xzf kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz

# copy custom server.properties into image 
COPY ./server.properties ./

# Set working directory to kafka dir
WORKDIR /home/$APPUSER/kafka_2.11-2.1.0

# start kafka with customer server.properties file
CMD ["bin/kafka-server-start.sh", "../server.properties"]
```

### zookeeper.dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.7

# Set the name for a non-priliaged user
ENV APPUSER=appuser

# Install dependnacies
RUN apk add bash
RUN apk add openjdk8-jre

# Add a non-privilaged user and change into it's home directory
RUN adduser -D $APPUSER
WORKDIR /home/$APPUSER

# Download kafka and set its owner to $APPUSER
RUN wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz
RUN chown $APPUSER kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz

# Change to the non-privilaged user
USER $APPUSER

# Extract kafka
RUN tar -xzf kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz

# Set working directory to kafka dir
WORKDIR /home/$APPUSER/kafka_2.11-2.1.0

# Run zookeeper
CMD ["bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh", "config/zookeeper.properties"]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're brewing your own Kafka and ZK docker images, when they exist pre-built already? https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/

Comment: As a learning exercise. Although I think I actually got a similar error when I used a pre-built image.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe start with the pre-built images, since networking and Kafka config can be fiddly. Once you've got that working, move onto the DIY image.

Comment: playing around with both my setup and the pre-built images as you suggested seems to have highlighted the problem. If I use `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` instead of `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.109:9092` everything works. Any idea why?

Comment: Turns out it was my firewall setup!

Answer (score 3):

This is down to the listeners configuration.

When you specify `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.109:9092` then Kafka will try to connect to `192.168.0.109` from *within the Docker container*. But if this is a host address, and if you've not set up the appropriate Docker networking wizardry, it will fail.

When you specify `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` then Kafka will connect to `localhost` within the Docker container, which of course resolves to *itself*. The catch here is that you would be unable to use a Kafka client outside of the Docker container (either on your host machine, or another Docker container) because they would try to connect to `localhost`—*locally to themselves* on which there would not be a Kafka broker.

[This article](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) explains in more detail the issue, and appropriate configuration to use. If you want a pre-built example of Kafka in Docker then [this Docker Compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/community-components-only/docker-compose.yml#L22-L51) shows it.